# need to create a dialog box in jQuery which can act as form

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create Dialog box which can show form where i can refresh the page content on submition.

I want to open a calculator in dialog box . On giving input after submitting the value. the calculation should be updated the table in same view. in same dialog box.

i m using JQuery and for submitting data i m using controller. kindly guide me how to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jquery UI dialog 
  http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Create a form with id 'calculator-form' and call it dialog as below.

```
$( "#calculator-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function() {
                        //you can get the controls on the main page and do you logic here and close the dialog
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
```